# Is an admisible heuristic always monotone (consistent)?

Tags: heuristics

For the A* search algorithm, provided an heuristic h, supose h is admisible.

That is:

> h(n) ≤  h*(n) for every node n, where h* is the real cost from n to **goal**.

Does this ensure the heuristic is monotone?

That is:

> f(n) ≤ g(n') + h(n') for every sucesor n' of n, where f(n)= h(n) + g(n) and g(n) is the accumulated cost.

Comment: Nope.  Almost any breadth first search will generate values that don't move you closer to the goal.  But you don't know which values are useful until you've generated them.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Assume you have three successor states `s1`, `s2`, `s3` and a goal state `g` so that `s1 -> s2 -> s3 -> g`.
 `s1` is the starting node.

Consider also the following values for `h(s)` and `h*(s)` (i.e. true cost):
`h(s1) = 3 , h*(s1) = 6`
`h(s2) = 4 , h*(s2) = 5`
`h(s3) = 3 , h*(s3) = 3`
`h(g) = 0 , h*(g) = 0`

Following the only path to the goal we can have that:

`g(s1) = 0, g(s2) = 1, g(s3) = 3, g(g) = 6`, coinciding with the true cost above.

Although the heuristic function is admissible (`h(s) <= h*(s)`), `f(n)` will not be monotonic. For instance `f(s1) = h(s1) + g(s1) = 3` while `f(s2) = h(s2) + g(s2) = 5` with `f(s1) < f(s2)`. Same holds between `f(s2)` and `f(s3)`.

Of course this means you have a quite uninformative heuristic.